# assert to check the value available in the column of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, assert

```
def director_release_year(director_df,filter_column,director_name):
    if filter_column not in director_df.columns:
        raise Exception("the column is not available in the DataFrame")
    # Tests that the the column value is in the dataframe
    if director_name in director_df[filter_column].tolist()== False:
           raise ValueError("the column don't have the value")
    
    #filter the dataframe based on the given director_name
    df=director_df[director_df[filter_column]==director_name]
    
    # return the result
    return df
```

if i give the unavailable value for director_name the output is a empty df instead of this exception error

```
    movie_title release_date    hero    villian song    name    director    release_year
```

I tried the following assert , but the result is one or other error not the exact assert i set for

```
 assert director_name in director_df[director_name].values,"The name does not exist in the director column"
o/p:
```

KeyError: 'siva'

```
 assert director_df[filter_column].isin([director_name]),"The name does not exist in the director column"
o/p:
```

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write

```py
if (director_df[filter_column] != director_name).all():
    raise ValueError("the column don't have the value")
```

The condition above basically checks if all values in `director_df[filter_column]` does not equal `director_name`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are checking a string `director_name` in a dataframe `director_df`, it results in a series of bool values. So its better to check for conditionality using `.any()` or `.all()`. This concept is clearly explained in this [Reference link](https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-valueerror-truth-value-series-ambiguous-use-empty-bool-item-any-or-all/#Usinganyandall).

```
if not (director_df['filter_column'] == director_name).any():
    raise ValueError
```